# Why when moving the mouse over the colored item of ContextMenu it keep draw/color the item over and over again?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I did that when you make right mosue lcick on item on dataGridView1 it will open a ContextMenu and will color in Red the last item in the contextMenu:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

            int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

            if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
            {

                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
                m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
                m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
                m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].MeasureItem += MeasureMenuItem;
            }

            m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        }
    }
```

This is the Cm_DrawItem event:

```
void Cm_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MenuItem)sender;
            var g = e.Graphics;
            var font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
            var brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            g.DrawString(item.Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
```

This is the MeasureMenuItem event:

```
void MeasureMenuItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem m = (MenuItem)sender;
            Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style);
            SizeF sze = e.Graphics.MeasureString(m.Text, font);
            e.ItemHeight = (int)sze.Height;
            e.ItemWidth = (int)sze.Width;
        }
```

This is the result i get once i make right click with the mouse:

[image]

And then if i jusr move the mouse cursor over the colored/drawed last item in red it keep drawing it and make it look like this:

[image]

It keep drawing over and over the last item and keep color it in Red more and more.
How can i avoid from this to happen ?

Comment: You keep registering to the event. Register only once.

Comment: Rotem give me an example please about how to check if the event was registered already or not ? ( according to my code ).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you don't erase the background of the menu-item.  So you'll paint on top of pixels that are already present.  The anti-aliasing pixels that the text renderer draws will start to try to blend it into pixels that are pinkish instead of the item's background color.  Making those pixels increasingly more red.  The visual effect is that the letter shape gets increasingly blobby looking since the anti-aliasing color is no longer correct.  As though you draw a red letter on a red background.

The simplest way to do this without causing flicker is to use the [TextRenderer.DrawText() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3cdh3zw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the Rectangle and two Color arguments so that both the foreground and background are drawn.  Use TextRenderer.MeasureText in your MeasureMenuItem event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear menu before adding menu items.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();

        m.MenuItems.Clear(); // clear menu before adding new items
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

        int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
        {

            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
            m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
            m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
            m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].MeasureItem += MeasureMenuItem;
        }

        m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    }
}
```